# WordPress and WooCommerce - How many products are too many?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, server-load

I have imported about 12,000 WooCommerce products into WordPress. I think my site isn't working anymore because of that. Is 12,000 products really to much for WordPress to handle?

Comment: In what context are you running your WooCommerce shop? Is it on localhost? Shared hosting server? Do you have any other log files to share? Any Errors displayed?

Comment: Can you be more specific about "not working anymore"? Does the site not load at all? Does the homepage not load? Does search not work? Do you see heavy load on your server, or on your database server, or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, that is not the issue with your website, according to the WooCommerce FAQ: **[What is the maximum WooCommerce can handle?](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-scaling-faqs/#section-3)**

> Sky is the limit. We’ve seen instances of shops with 100,000+ products
>   listed, handling thousands of transactions per minute. In those cases,
>   they had great hosting support and their own developer team focused on
>   optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, WordPress and WooCommerce can handle as many products as you can load in.  The real questions here should be, **What can your server/host handle**?  Where you are hosting, what kind of hosting you have and how it's setup will be the main factors.

It's not how many products you have necessarily but how many transactions you process simultaneously, and how many products you are querying at one time.

This sums it up pretty good, from *dougaitken at Automattic*...

> The real question you want to ask is around order processing.
>
> You can have 1 million products loaded on your site and 1 sale a day,
> your site will have hardly any problems as long as you don’t load many
> products on each page the customer visits.
>
> If you have 10 products but you have hundreds/thousands of orders an
> hour, that is when you could run into trouble.
>
> A big misconception is around WooCommerce and “number of products” it
> can handle. The real question is whether your server/hosting can
> handle the daily traffic and order processing you will have.
>
> Here are some links and a video related directly to your question:
>
> - https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-scaling-faqs/
> - https://www.wpintense.com/2016/08/16/scaling-woocommerce-1-million-products-talk-wordcamp-brighton/
> - https://hollerwp.com/scaling-woocommerce/

[original link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/woocommerce-can-hold-1-million-products/)